# how to remove () charracter

Tags: iphone, ios4

when i convert my array by following method , it adds () charracter.

i want to remove the () how can i do it..

```
NSMutableArray *rowsToBeDeleted = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSString *postString = 
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", 
rowsToBeDeleted];

int index = 0;

for (NSNumber *rowSelected in selectedArray)
{
  if ([rowSelected boolValue])
  {
    profileName = [appDelegate.archivedItemsList objectAtIndex:index];
    NSString *res = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",profileName.userID];
    [rowsToBeDeleted addObject:res];
  }
  index++;
}
```

UPDATE - 1
when i print my array it shows like this

(
    70,
    71,
    72
)

Comment: And what is in your array? Since i dont see anything in this code that would add it. Try NSLogging the array at the start to see exactly which items are in, then we know if it's already in the array or being added later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a brief example of deleting the given characters from a string.

```
NSString *someString = @"(whatever)";
NSCharacterSet *charSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"()"];
NSMutableString *mutableCopy = [NSMutableString stringWithString:someString];
NSRange range;
for (range = [mutableCopy rangeOfCharacterFromSet:charSet];
     range.location != NSNotFound;
     [mutableCopy deleteCharactersInRange:range],
     range = [mutableCopy rangeOfCharacterFromSet:charSet]);
```

All this does is get a mutable copy of the string, set up a character set with any and all characters to be stripped from the string, and find and remove each instance of those characters from the mutable copy.  This might not be the cleanest way to do it (I don't know what the cleanest is) - obviously, you have the option of doing it Ziminji's way as well.  Also, I abused a `for` loop for the hell of it.  Anyway, that deletes some characters from a string and is pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

Try using NSArray’s `componentsJoinedByString` method to convert your array to a string:

```
[rowsToBeDeleted componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the parenthesis is because you are calling the toString method on the NSArray class. Therefore, it sounds like you just want to substring the resulting string.  To do this, you can use a function like the following:

```
+ (NSString *) extractString: (NSString *)string prefix: (NSString *)prefix suffix: (NSString *)suffix {
    int strLength = [string length];
    int begIndex = [prefix length];
    int endIndex = strLength - (begIndex + [suffix length]);
    if (endIndex > 0) {
        string = [string substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(begIndex, endIndex)];
    }
    return string;
}
```